# CSS :nth-child(even) Selector background-color not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to display a background-color on two rows evenly using `:nth-child(even)` and it doesnt work, but it worked on jsfiddle.net (without the javascript to generate the table).

Generates a table after calling the JSON file -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("js/dataPokerPlayers.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, data){
            $(".tableData tbody").append("<tr><td class=\"centertext\">" + data.rank + "</td><td>" + data.name + "</td><td class=\"centertext\">" + data.earnings + "</td><td class=\"centertext\">" + data.points + "</td><td class=\"centertext\">" + data.totalearnings + "</td></tr>");
        });
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.tableData tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#212121;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="tableData">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th width="250">Name</th>
        <th>Earnings</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Total Earnings</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you paste your table with the `<tr>`s that are being generated?

Comment: Check to make sure the _tds_ background is transparent

Comment: The selector works fine in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ttXR/) even when creating the rows dynamically in javascript. Just as a side-note. It is less confusing to read and update the strings if you use single `'` on the outside and `"` in the inner text, that way no need to escape them. Easier on the eye and to maintain. i.e: `'<tr><td class="centertext">a</td><td>b</td><td class="centertext">c</td><td class="centertext"></td>d<td class="centertext">e</td></tr>'`

Comment: I have made nearly the same fiddle as @FrançoisWahl and I can confirm that it is, in fact, working. There must be something else in your CSS overriding this. Can you check in a developer tool the source of the current background color in your css?

Comment: Ejay, yeah, I had two colors like this background-color: and color: in the td selector and it worked just fine. I could have thought about that - duh! Thank you!

Comment: @Filburt: That's not a "tag prefix". The colon is part of the `:nth-child()` selector. Don't just remove a language name from the title purely based on the language name and nearest punctuation.

Comment: @Christian ok that's great :)

Comment: All hail the mighty lord @Ejay ... We are not worthy of your powers.

Answer (score 2):

The following CSS code will work.

```
.tableData > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n) {
background-color:#212121;}
```